# forking of few independent events from the main program

Tags: perl, fork

I am trying to develop a desktop app for twitter. For authorization purpose I am using the module `Browser::Open` to open the default browser system , which provide a pin need to be entered by the end user in to the desktop app.

I am opening the browser using fork, the script is not is not getting stopped to take input of the pin after authorization and in other case user need to close the browser before entering the pin.

Here is code. (with and without forking)

```
    unless ( $nt->authorized ) {
        print "authorization of the url";
        my $url =  $nt->get_authorization_url;
        print "Authorize this app at ", $nt->get_authorization_url, " and enter the PIN#\n";
        if (1) {
            my $pid = fork();
            print "\$pid : $pid";
            if ($pid) {
                open_browser($url);
                push @childId,$pid;
            }
        } else {
            open_browser($url);
        }
        print "please enter the pin u got on screen\n";
        my $pin = <STDIN>; #wait for input
        chomp $pin;
        #`kill -9 $pid`;

    }
```

Any way I can manage these event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$pid` is true in the parent process and `0` in the child process, so I think your logic should be

```
if ($pid) {
    # parent
    push @childId,$pid;
} else {
    # child
    open_browser($url);
    exit;                # <------ DON'T FORGET TO EXIT THE CHILD
}
```